# How to add a block file i.e., .phtml file to to the sales.xml in magento when the order is viewed from magento admin panel

Tags: php, magento

I want to add a button when an order is viewed from the `magento` admin panel.Actually i have done by hard-coding in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/sales/order/view/info.phtml` file. the button added is got reflected in the admin when the order is viewed. But the thing known to us is the core `magento` files cannot be modified.

So what i did is i have moved the html code for the button into another `mybutton.phtml` file and i wanted to display before the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/sales/order/view/info.phtml` in the `sales.xml` file in the `< adminhtml_sales_order_view >` tag. I have done this in `local.xml`(my own file) file using `< reference >` tag where the layout customization are done. But after doing this i got a warning

Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`  in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.phtml.`

Please give me a solution that helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

raghav, You need to override the mage block app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php 
Add the following code to the constructor

```
    $this->_addButton('order_reorder', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('My Button'),
        'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl('path/of/url') . '\')',
    ));
```